# Mysterious error in tkz-tab

Tags: tkz-tab

I am not getting why I get an error in there :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabColors[backgroundcolor=fondExercice]
        \tkzTabInit[lgt=5,espcl=2.5]{$x$ /0.6,$-12x^2+4$ /0.6,$(x^2+1)^3$/.6,$f''(x)$ /.6,$f(x)$/1.2}{$-\infty$, $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}3$,$\frac{\sqrt3}3$,$+\infty$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,z,+,z,-,}
        \tkzTabLine{,+,t,+,t,+,}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,z,+,z,-,}
        \tkzTabLine{,,,,}
        \draw ($(Z14) + (3mm,0)$) to[out=40,in=140] ($(Z24) + (-3mm,0)$);
        \draw ($(Z24) + (3mm,0)$) to[out=-40,in=-140] ($(Z34) + (-3mm,0)$);
        %\draw ($(Z34) + (3mm,0)$) to[out=40,in=140] ($(Z44) + (-3mm,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the line`\draw ($(Z34) + (3mm,0)$) to[out=40,in=140] ($(Z44) + (-3mm,0)$);` there is an issue and I don't get why.

Looking at the doc, that (Z44) node should exist.

If anyone has a clue ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add two more commas to `\tkzTabLine{,,,,}`, i.e., change it to `\tkzTabLine{,,,,,,}`. All your TabLines have 7 entries and therefore 6 commas. `Z44` only exists if the corresponding table entry is created.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thanks. But I thought that if one line had 7 entries, all would have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.